# How can I make a SQL Server database inherit users and role memberships when they are attached?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, utilities

When I attach a database I would like for several users to be created on it and for them to be assigned to certain fixed database roles.  Any way to ensure that this happens automatically (potentially for hundreds of databases being attached at one time) or are there any tools / utilities out there for this sort of thing?

If there's no way to do this for attaching databases, is there a way to do it for newly created databases?  For example, if I add the users and the roles to the model database, will those objects and membership be inherited by newly created databases?  It doesn't seem to work so far.

Comment: Are you interested in adding new users to the SQL Server instance or the newly attached databases, or are you looking to resolve orphaned users?

Comment: I'm interested in adding users to the newly attached databases and mapping them to existing logins on the SQL Server instance.  I'm not sure about resolving orphaned users... would that help me?  Those users don't exist in my organization and I wouldn't know what logins to map them to.  If I understand correctly, I don't think I want to worry about the orphaned users.

Answer (score 0):

A way to handle this by an activation initiated via the SQL Server Service Broker Event:

[Implementing Internal Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff663135.aspx)

Comment: Hmmm... could you give me a little more info so I can cut through the documentation a bit faster?  Thanks.

Comment: Would using a DDL Trigger be an appropriate way of handling this?  I've been looking into this, but the Event() function looks like a mess to get information out of.

Comment: In fact, using a DDL Trigger was a great way to handle this -- and so much more.  Love it.  The Event() function is a mess, but there are plenty of examples of it to help you figure out how to get what you need.